# Links in dendogram - hierarchy layout D3.JS

Tags: javascript, d3.js

So, I have been trying to visualize the popular tree of life data using dendogram layout of d3.js exactly similar to that of http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063570.

I have problem with the links in the diagram as you can see in screenshot. I have also posted the code don't know where exactly I am going wrong.

```
var svg = d3.select("svg"),
        width = +svg.attr("width"),
        height = +svg.attr("height"),
        g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(40,0)");

var tree = d3.cluster()
        .size([height, width - 160]);


d3.text("test.txt", function(error, data) {
    if (error) throw error;

    var dat = parseNewick(data);

    console.log(dat);
    var root = d3.hierarchy(dat)
            .sort(function(a,b){return b.height - a.height });

    tree(root);

    var link = g.selectAll(".link")
            .data(root.descendants().slice(1))
            .enter().append("path")
            .attr("class", "link")
            .attr("d", function(d) {
                return "M" + d.y + "," + d.x
                        + "C" + (d.parent.y + 100) + "," + d.x
                        + " " + (d.parent.y + 100) + "," + d.parent.x
                        + " " + d.parent.y + "," + d.parent.x;
            });

    var node = g.selectAll(".node")
            .data(root.descendants())
            .enter().append("g")
            .attr("class", function(d) { return "node" + (d.children ? " node--internal" : " node--leaf"); })
            .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")"; })

    node.append("circle")
            .attr("r", 2.5);
```

[image]
    });

Comment: Looks like a data problem, so without seeing your `test.txt`, it's impossible to answer this question.

Comment: The data I am using is life.txt as here https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/c034d66572fd6bd6815a and it is parsed using the newick.js just as in the same example. I am then using hierarchy layout to get the root which is passed to the cluster layout.

Comment: THe two example that you are referencing, one was written with the version 3 of d3.j and the other with version 4. There was a fair amount of changes made between both versions. If you are trying to combine both of these examples it may be the cause of your issue. One thing that I don't see in your code is the assignment of the parentId `var stratify = d3.stratify()
    .parentId()` is a line in your first example... maybe something to look into.